# Html5 video not seekable

Tags: html5-video, mp4, flowplayer

I dont' really know if this is a SO question or SF question.

I'm using flowplayer 5.2.0. The video is prepared for streaming using ffmpeg (moov moved to file head, encoded with h.264 and etc). But, using debug: true option i see the following output:

```
Object {url: "http://188.254.8.34/video/2012/03/20/jvk6abVbQog.mp4", seekpoints: Array[20], src: "http://188.254.8.34/video/2012/03/20/jvk6abVbQog.mp4", width: 1280, seekable: false…}
```

This media file is not seekable. But:

```
debug.metadata Object {videoframerate: 25, seekpoints: Array[20], audiocodecid: "mp4a", moovposition: 40, audiochannels: 2…}
```

There are some seekpoints.

What should i do to make this file seekable?

Mp4's are served by nginx with mp4 module -- range requests are supported.

*EDIT*:

I have a hypothesis that i need to fragment mp4 by keyframes. But i don't know how to do it with ffmpeg v.>0.8.

Comment: Did you read this: http://flowplayer.org/docs/index.html#server-side ? ... maybe your server doesn't support byte range requests ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like flowplayer (it's non-flash version) does not support HTTP Progressive download. It's flash version does, however.